# Jackson -- Recursively replace matched fields

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

Given the following (serialized from a POJO), I need to encrypt each occurrence of a list of fields, regardless of their depth, based on field name(s).  As an example, I would like to encrypt certain parts of the document for storage (password and quantityOrdered).

I have the encryption piece taken care of, but looking for a good approach to traverse the JsonNode, finding each occurrence of the matched field and encrypting/replace it.

Hiding (via @JsonIgnore for example, wouldn't solve the problem as I need the data to be stored).  This is for an offline, file-backup of some system data.

Note that of the fields I want to match (passsword and quantityOrdered), they are of different types and password appears multiple times, at different levels.

```
{
  "name":"foo",
  "id":"123456",
  "password":"bar",
  "communities": [
    {
      "name":"administrators",
      "location":"xyz",
      "password":"baz"
    },
    {
      "name":"members",
      "location":"xyz",
      "password":"baz"
    }
  ],
  "quantityOrdered": 35
}
```

Examples I see of using the tree model imply knowledge of the structure of the document.  I saw that JsonNode.getElements() could be used to get all elements of a name, but it only returns the values, not the keys.  Can somebody with experience in this recommend a good approach to take.

Comment: Maybe you could just simply ignore those properties by marking them with `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: ^^ that. Why serialize the fields at all?

Comment: The comments above were more relevant with my original question which was somewhat ambiguous about my intentions.  I must save the field and the value (in a reversibly encrypted format)

Comment: The simplest way: you can encrypt full `JSON` string and save the result. Deserialization will be simple also: decrypt data to `JSON` and deserialize `JSON` to `POJO`. What do you think?

Comment: Well I specifically have to encrypt only particular fields, by pattern matching their names... This is being used to store an offline backup, and like my example, I have to store the password in encrypted format.  So the questions is about how best to traverse a full JSON tree (that was serialized from a pojo) and replace the values for nodes that I find whose name matches a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Custom JsonFilter, and overwrite the serializeAsField method.

```
@Override
public void serializeAsField(Object bean, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov, BeanPropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
    if (writer.getName().equals("name")) {
        // encrypt the value
    } else {
        // The property will not be filtered
        writer.serializeAsField(bean, jgen, prov);
    }
}
```